# How do I solve $y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

This is what I have so far:

$y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$

$ y'=\frac{x}{x+y}-\frac{y}{x+y}$

$ y'=\frac{1}{1+\frac{y}{x}}-\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+1} $

Make a substitution here:

$v=\frac{y}{x}, y=vx, y'=v'x+v$

$ v'x+v = \frac{1}{1+v}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{v}+1}$

Do I just simplify the right side here, and then separate variables?  When I tried this, I got:

$\int \frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^2}dv = lnx+C_0$

I didn't know how to solve the integral here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the relation between the numerator and the denominator in the integral. What happens when you differentiate the denominator?

Comment: @Beni Hahaha!  I see it now.  Thanks!

Comment: Good, Korgan. Now you can write up and post an answer (the software may make you wait a while to do this), and then later you can accept your answer. That helps clean up the Unanswered Questions list.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating it. Sum $1$ to both sides to get $$y'+1=\frac{x-y}{x+y}+1=\frac{2x}{x+y}.$$ Now, because $(x+y)'=y'+1$, we get $$(x+y)'=\frac{2x}{x+y}.$$
Familiar, right? Write $u=y+x$, so $u'=2x/u \implies u^2/2=x^2+A$. We finally have $$y=-x\pm\sqrt{2x^2+B}.$$

Comment: I don't think the answer is right. It will be $y=-x\pm\sqrt{2x^2+A}$. By the way the technique is good.

Comment: @Rana Indeed, thank you. But why the $2$ in $2x^2$? We are integrating $2x$.

Comment: I really like this technique too.  I hadn't considered it.  But yeah, there should be a 2 in there.

Comment: @IanMateus The 2 comes from when you integrate u, then multiply out the $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Rana, KorganRivera thank you, I understand it now. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I've included all the working, in case anyone else requires it.  Hopefully no typos.

$y'=\frac{x-y}{x+y}$

$ y'=\frac{x}{x+y}-\frac{y}{x+y}$

$ y'=\frac{1}{1+\frac{y}{x}}-\frac{1}{\frac{x}{y}+1} $

Make a substitution here:

$v=\frac{y}{x}, y=vx, y'=v'x+v$

$ v'x+v = \frac{1}{1+v}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{v}+1}$

$\int \frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^2}dv = lnx+C_0$

Make another substitution here:

$ u=1-2v-v^2, \frac{du}{dv}=-2(1+v), dv=\frac{du}{-2(1+v)} $

$\int \frac{1+v}{u} \frac{du}{-2(1+v)} = lnx+C_0$

$-\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{u} du = lnx+C_0$

$ -\frac{1}{2} lnu = lnx+C_1$

$-\frac{1}{2}ln(1-2v-v^2)=lnx+C_1$

$ln(1-2v-v^2)=-2lnx+C_2$

$e^{-2lnx+C_2}=1-2v-v^2$

$C_3x^{-2}=1-2v-v^2$

$v^2+2v-1 = C_4x^{-2}$

Complete the square to get:

$v=-1\pm\sqrt{C_3x^{-2}+2}=\frac{y}{x}$

$y=-x\pm x \sqrt{C_3x^{-2}+2}$

$y =-x \pm \sqrt{C_3+2x^2}$

Comment: Your last simplification is off the mark - you've lost the initial $x$ term (the one outside the square root).  Other than that, though, this looks spot-on.

Comment: Your plus in the denominator somehow became a minus.

Comment: @Mike oh yeah, oops.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Ok thanks.  Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this integral by using the partial fractions technique.
But tell me this. That simplification is correct? You got this result below:
$$\int \frac{1+v}{1-2v-v^2}dv$$

I've got this one:

$$\int \frac{1-v}{1-v}dv$$

That is 1 if v is different than 1, right?

Am I off the track here?

You got $$ \frac{1}{1-v}- \frac{1}{\frac{1}{v}-1} = K$$

$$\therefore  K = \frac{1}{1-v} -\frac{1}{\frac{1-v}{v}} $$

$$  \therefore K = \frac{1}{1-v} - \frac{v}{1-v}  $$

$$ \therefore K = \frac{1-v}{1-v}=1$$

So v can't be 0 and can't be 1 neither.